# How to change the "Return-Path" header on email notification

Tags: php, email

Can any one please advice how do i change the mailing header `Return-Path`

from `<apache@326932-web2.domain.co.uk>` to `fromemail@example.com`, since the notification emails are get into SPAM/JUNK folder.

`Note:` I have been advised to change this info on the mail sending code(PHP)

Comment: After fixing the bug "Return-Path", I have received another error says "could not receive server domain 326932-web2.domain.co.uk" for some cases...

Comment: Also, in the list of email rejection screen it shows "DNS resolve failed". any idea why it has happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what i do and works every time

```
mail($to,$subject,$body,'From: fromemail@example.com','-f fromemail@example.com');
```

Comment: I have received an error says "could not receive server domain 326932-web2.domain.co.uk" for some cases...any idea?

Comment: are you sending alot? i know hosting servers cutoff after a certain amount of emails going out.  For example: Godaddy allows 150 per day.  Not sure if that's it but you might wanna check it out.

Comment: Hey, It has been used on "forgot password", the count may based on the user's request, it may about 5 or whet ever.

Comment: This info is a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

In the headers parameters of the `mail()` function you can set this:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Return-Path: fromemail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Note: I have been advised to change this info on the mail sending code(PHP)

You should follow that advice :-D

Just add a `From: fromemail@example.com \r\n` to the header of the mail that will be sent.

Comment: The From header is different to the Return-Path header. You need both set in the email header ideally.