# php email doesn't send from specified From: address

Tags: php

When I run this script to send an email, the email is being sent from serveradmin@myhosting. They say that the script isn't configured correctly.

I've changed the domain names and info shown below before posting here.

Is there really a problem with the scrip? The email sends, everything is fine.
It takes a bit long...don't know why, the only problem is it doesn't send from the domain I specified.

```
    $to = $_POST['fes-email'];
    $subject = 'TEST';

    $body = 'TEST TEST';

    $headers =  'From: NAME \(Info\) <name@domain.tld>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: name@domain.tld' . "\r\n" .
                'Return-Path: name@domain.tld' . "\r\n" .

                'X-Priority: 1' . "\r\n" .
                'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .


    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the backslashes before the parentheses? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: It does. Just doesn't display whatever is written inside the parentheses. I am using the backslashes to escape the parentheses. Like you would use backslashes to escape double quotes inside double quotes, or single inside single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using quotes instead of escaping the parentheses:

```
$headers = 'From: "NAME (Info)" <name@domain.tld>' . "\r\n" .
```

You should remove the `Return-path:` header. This header is always recreated by the receiving server, using the envelope information sent via SMTP.

Comment: The name appeared like is should without having to escape. However, when I looked at the headers `Return-Path: <serveradmin@hostingdomain>`, and also the envelope is signed by the same address. I am on media temple if that makes a difference, shouldn't.

Comment: `Return-path` is not settable by client applications. The receiving server creates that header by using the envelope sender address.

Comment: First time I'm playing with php email...going off what the hosting said. This is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622808/how-to-change-the-return-path-header-on-email-notification) they suggested.

Comment: I think if you need to customize the envelope sender, that will have to be done in the PHP configuration. I'm not sure where.

Comment: Will something like this do anything `mail('to@blah.com','subject!','body!','From: from@blah.com','-f from@blah.com');`? [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179014/how-to-change-envelope-from-address-using-php-mail)

Comment: `-f` is used to set the `From:` address, not the envelope sender.

Comment: Maybe adding a `Sender:` line to `$headers` will work, but I doubt it. I suspect you need to do something in `php.ini`.

Comment: Maybe something in http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks...I'll check with the hosting again. As for this answer, I like the quotes instead of having to escape. So thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting just `<name@domain.tld>` in the headers for From?

Comment: I have...same thing. Just I'd like to also add a name. More appealing that way